# getElevation and setElevation methods

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I know that `ActionBar.getElevation()` and `ActionBar.setElevation(float)` methods were added since API 21 but I want to achieve this on API 19 too.

Is there any way to programmatically elevate an ActionBar (z-index) without using external libraries?

Comment: v7 support library: android default

Answer (score 0):

You could use new material [Toolabar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) instead of typical ActionBar. It doesn't have elevation by default and it is available from support libs.

Comment: I need to have it on a kitkat device.

Comment: @xpirt It is available in AppCompat v7 so also on KitKat. Check [this](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/) out.